# ASP.NET Run installed app on client from website

Tags: asp.net, .net, printing, client

Is it possible to run a .NET app which I've installed on the client's machine from my web app? And can I pass data to it?

Basically I'm trying to send HTML/PDF directly to the default printer without invoking the browser's print dialogue.

**EDIT**

I probably wasn't clear of what I'm trying to achieve. When a client clicks on "Print Invoice" I would like to bypass the browser's print dialogue and send the invoice straight to the default printer for printing. I am able to get my clients to install an app on their machine for this purpose if there is no other way.

Comment: "You've installed"? Does that mean you have administrator access to the user's machine? And why not just print from the server?

Comment: The client wants the print not me, what good printing on the server would do? I can provide my client with an app to install for this purpose, if there is no other way.

Comment: If you don't have administrative rights to the client computer, you can't execute a program remotely on a client's PC. Thing of the security implications if you were able to do that! But if your clients are willing to install a program, you can have that program always running on their PC, perhaps as a Windows Service or a system tray application. Have the app always connect to your server, so you can tell it when and what to print.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you're suggesting a round trip from the web app to the server and then the server to the Windows app/service? That's probably a bit too long to wait for a print out. Any other way?

Comment: Why do you think it's a bit too long to wait? What qualifies as "too long" to you?

Comment: How long do you think (worst case scenario) it would take? Customers don't expect to wait for invoices/receipts after payment, specially if there's a queue waiting to be served.

Comment: It could be less than a second. It could be a couple seconds. Have a look at SignalR, which would allow your app to maintain a constant connection to your server.